# make sure openfire does not connect to other jabber servers

Tags: security, xmpp, openfire

This is mostly a security question; i've installed [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) jabber service on my office network, but i want to make sure the server is not using federation or any other interactions without outside jabber servers, so its entirely local

any ideas how to make sure of this?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you simply don't configure the features you do not want - I believe it just configures itself to deliver local services by default.